# Assign inventory source if distance greater than 20km

Tags: magento2, msi, multi-source-inventory

I am using the distance priority algorithm for source selection of the inventory. I want to assign a particular source to a product if the nearest available source is greater than 20km distance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should tweak the method

```
\Magento\InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection\Model\Algorithms\DistanceBasedAlgorithm::getEnabledSourcesOrderedByDistanceByStockId
```

This method sorts sources by distances.